# redirecting stdout to a thread specific file in OpenMP

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, openmp

environment: linux, gcc 3.8, openmp 4.5 (part of gcc), hw 2 cores, 4 threads

I have a C++ program with a calculation that is bona fide thread safe, except that it
also writes to stdout. I am trying to parallelize this with OpenMP, trying to redirect
each thread's cout stream to a separate file. This is failing, surely I am not correctly
doing the redirection. Here is an example program:

```
#include <omp.h>
using namespace std;
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>

double calc1() {
  const int MAXIT=100000000;
  double x,res = 0.0;
  int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();
  for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {
    for (int i=0; i<MAXIT; i++) {
      x = i;
      x = sqrt(x);
    }
    res += x*x;
    cout << " thread_id = " << thread_id << " j = " << j << endl; 
  }
  return res;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  int nThreads;
  int nThreadsMax = omp_get_max_threads();

  if (argc==1) {
    nThreads = nThreadsMax;
  }
  else {
    nThreads = atoi(argv[1]);
  }
  cout << "using " << nThreads << " threads" << endl;
  
  // log file name for each thread
  vector<ofstream*> of;
  for (int nt=0; nt<nThreads; nt++) {
    of.push_back( new ofstream( "thr_" + to_string(nt) + ".log" ) );
  }
  
  omp_set_num_threads(nThreads);
 
  streambuf* coutbuf = cout.rdbuf(); // save old buf
#pragma omp parallel for
  for (int nt=0; nt<nThreads; nt++) {
    cout.rdbuf(of[nt]->rdbuf()); //redirect std::cout to threadLogFile!

    double res = calc1(); // "slow" calculation that writes to stdout but otherwise threadsafe

    cout << "nt = " << nt << " res = " << res << endl;
    cout.flush(); cout.rdbuf(coutbuf); //reset to standard output again
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Running this produces empty thread logfiles except one that contains most of the
output lines. Those that are not there show up in the main stdout, like this

```
$ ./omp_3 3
using 3 threads
 thread_id = 1 j = 9
nt = 1 res = 1e+09
 thread_id = 2 j = 9
nt = 2 res = 1e+09
```

Would appreciate any hints of how to correctly do this. Thanks!

Comment: `cout` is a global object, you can't redirect it to different streams simultaneously. You'll have to pass your per-thread stream object to the `calc1()` function and write output directly into it instead of `cout`.

Comment: Was afraid of that. Sorry I didn't mention that the slow calculation is a large sw package that isn't under my control. Had hoped to find a neat trick to parallelize that for use on many-core machines.

Comment: Well, you could fork instead.

Comment: Do you have access to the source of that sw package or are you stuck with a library that writes to cout?

Comment: Hi, I do have access to the source on gitlab, so in principle I can make a clone.

Comment: The sw I am using has around 2k uses of cout/cerr. I could change these to write to an ofstream, but this is non backwards compatible and would also require future changes to stick to this form of output (maybe simplified by a macro). Not clear the authors would accept such changes and stick to them. If not, I would be stuck with maintaining a parallel version myself. For now I am exploring the other suggestion of forking. I